# Get all words in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen this question a few times but all seem to ask questions differently than mine thus I'm having a few problems trying to wrap my head around how i'd handle what i'm trying to do.

I have a file that I create in node, basically a JSON object stringified.

I read the file like so :

```
fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    console.log(data.search("generated_images"));

    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
});
```

How can I do a search on the text file I have and find every time generated_images has been used in there?

I'm basically trying to get the word generated_images then grab characters after it so...

Everytime generated_images is used, count 80 characters after and write it to a new array or new text file I can read.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why not just parse the stringified JSON and traverse the object normally?

Comment: It doesn't contain JSON anymore, because I stringified it when writing it to a new file. I did `fs.writeFile('data.txt', JSON.stringify(data),  function(err) {)`

Comment: The output of JSON.stringify() *is* JSON. In other words, JSON is a string representation of an object. ([There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)) You use JSON.parse() to turn the string back into an actual object.

Comment: if data.txt contains json data, you can use ```JSON.parse(data)``` to get json object and traverse object normally to get your job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some discussion of JSON above, but in your question you specifically ask how to grab "80 chars after"... A regular expression is a fast way to achieve this. Consider this input text:

```
var data = 'asdf qwer asdf asfwe generated_images 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 adsf weqr asdfjkaekl zdfjhasdf generated_images abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab';
```

Then this code will return the results shown::

```
data.match(/generated_images .{0,80}/g);

['generated_images 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890',
 'generated_images abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab']
```